# AngularJS- understanding angular-seed module style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Many angular examples use simple global functions. Angular-seed and yo angular use a more complex coding style. Here is an example of a simple styled example from stackoverflow/jsbin: http://jsbin.com/lucit/8/edit

```
var app = angular.module( 'app', [] );
var MyFunc = function() {
  this.name = "default name";
  this.$get = function() {
      this.name = "new name"
      return "Hello from MyFunc.$get(). this.name = " + this.name;
  };
  return "Hello from MyFunc(). this.name = " + this.name; 
};
// returns the actual function
app.service( 'myService', MyFunc );
// returns the function's return value
app.factory( 'myFactory', MyFunc );
// returns the output of the function's $get function
app.provider( 'myProv', MyFunc );

function MainCtrl( $scope, myService, myFactory, myProv ) {
  $scope.serviceOutput = "service = "+ JSON.stringify(myService);
  $scope.factoryOutput = "factory = " + myFactory;
  $scope.providerOutput = "provider = " + myProv;
}
```

What follows is an attempt to rewrite a simple example in the  angular-seed module style: http://jsbin.com/hitun/4/edit

```
var MyFunc = function() {
  this.name = "default name";
  this.$get = function() {
      this.name = "new name"
      return "Hello from MyFunc.$get(). this.name = " + this.name;
  };
  return "Hello from MyFunc(). this.name = " + this.name; 
};       

angular.module('app', [
'app.controllers',
'app.services'
]);
angular.module('app.services',[])
  .factory('MainData', MyFunc)
  .service('MainData', MyFunc)
  .provider('MainData', MyFunc));

angular.module('app.controllers',[])
  .controller('MainCtrl', [function($scope, myService, myFactory, myProv){
    $scope.serviceOutput = "service = "+ JSON.stringify(myService);
    $scope.factoryOutput = "factory = " + myFactory;
    $scope.providerOutput = "provider = " + myProv;  
  }]);
```

No matter how I try to tweak the syntax, I get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line has a parenthesis too much:

```
.provider('MainData', MyFunc));
```

Change it to:

```
.provider('myProv', MyFunc);
```

The factory, service and provider are all named `MainData`, but in your `MainCtrl` you are trying to inject `myService`, `myFactory`, `myProv`.

Rename them:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])
.factory('myFactory', MyFunc)
.service('myService', MyFunc)
.provider('myProv', MyFunc);
```

Your controller definition is using the inline array notation. Notice the bracket in front of function:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', [function(
```

Change it to:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', 'myFactory', 'myProv',
  function($scope, myService, myFactory, myProv) {
```

Or remove both brackets:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService, myFactory, myProv) {
  $scope.serviceOutput = "service = " + JSON.stringify(myService);
  $scope.factoryOutput = "factory = " + myFactory;
  $scope.providerOutput = "provider = " + myProv;
});
```

You can read more about this in the [dependency injection documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/kipeyele/2/edit?html,output

Comment: Sorry for my sloppy work. I tried to get the inline array notation version to work without success http://jsbin.com/hitun/8/edit. On to figure out testing.

Comment: When using the inline array notiation the function must be last, and everything before it needs to be strings: .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', 'myFactory', 'myProv', function($scope, myService, myFactory, myProv)